# Why does IIS stop me from accessing this text file?

Tags: iis

Im having some trouble with basic IIS administration. I have created a site at C:\test\ with a document called test.htm. When I browse to testsite/test.htm iis is trowing an error saying it could not access the web.config. But the folder hasnt even got any asp.net resources in it. Whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

I just did the same as you:

- Created a new web site on C:\test
- Set its binding to port 81 (port 80 already used)
- Started the site
- Created a html test file test.htm in C:\test
- browsed http://localhost:81/test.htm and it worked

BTW - I used IIS 7.5

Answer (score 0):

Is your "testsite" even mapped to the C:\test folder?
If not that would not work. Make sure that the website is mapped to where the files are.

Default folder for the default web site is c:\inetpub\wwwroot

Good luck

Comment: yeah it is mapped I never have a problem with IIS do whatever I want until I start trying to set up this MVC project and I get problems :-(